# is there a way to translate from coordinates of one SVG to another when they have different transforms

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I've got a div containing two SVG's that are displayed one on top of the other:

```
<div class="container" id="container">
  <svg class="one" id="one" height="6000" width="6000">
    ...
  </svg>

  <svg class="two" id="two" height="6000" width="6000">
    ...
  </svg>
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
.container {
  perspective: 2600px;
  width: 6000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -4000px;
  display: grid;
}

.container .one {
  transform: rotateX(120deg);
  margin-bottom: -200px;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  z-index: 0;
}

.container .two {
  margin-bottom: -200px;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Is there any way to take coordinates on the "one" scale and convert them to the "two" scale?

I have attempted to create an SVG point and set it's x/y to a "one" coordinate and then go to screen coordinates and then back to "two" coordinates via

```
let point = one.createSVGPoint();

point.x = 3000;
point.y = 5268;

// SVGToScreen
point = point.matrixTransform(one.getScreenCTM());

// ScreenToSVG
point = point.matrixTransform(two.getScreenCTM().inverse());
```

but the resulting point is not drawn at the correct spot when added to "two".

Comment: I there any reason for using two <svg> elements one on top of anoter? You can do the same with two <g> elements with different transforms under a single svg

Comment: No, two svg's is not necessary. I have tried two <g>'s inside the same <svg> (one transformed and the other not) but have had no luck that way either.

And maybe I'm asking the wrong question. I want to transform the main <svg> (or <g> if you prefer) and then place another element on top of that UNTRANSFORMED but as if I were specifying the coordinates on the transformed scale.

Comment: I think it's not always possible... For example, if you rotate a <rect>, the transformed element cannot be drawn as <rect> (only as <path> or <polygon>). You can, obviously, calculate transformed coordinate for every point with transform matrix and draw simple elements based on those points.

Comment: Actually, that would be fine. Let's say I just want to perform the back-transformation for a single point only.